# Primes in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers

I have this definition of primes in my lecture notes and I don't understand it i was wondering whether someone could explain it to me

$p$ is prime if and only if for all $a$, $b$ that are elements of $R$, we have $p \mid ab$ implies $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

See I am rather lost by this definition.

Comment: Have you tried with the usual prime numbers to see if they fulfill that definition?

Comment: I have tried, but I'm attempting wrong, say I take 3 as a prime number 3|27 is true but, but 3 does not divide 2 or 7? am i missing something here?

Comment: The defining property of primes that you're used to from elementary school (the only divisors are itself and $1$) is in ring theory (with a suitable generalisation) called "irreducible" instead. For nice enough rings (like the integers) the concepts of prime and irreducible coincide. However, in general they are two different concepts.

Comment: $ab$ aren't digits, it's a product of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Thank you that makes so much sense:)

Comment: I thought you might got confused about prime with irreducible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element You could write down the definition of irreducible and primes and compare them. Their exact meaning based on the ring(ID etc.) they were the same in UFD.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried seeing why composite numbers don't fit that definition?

For example, take $p = 14$, $a = 2$, $b = 49$. Then $ab = 98$ is divisible by $p$. However, $2$ is clearly not divisible by $14$, nor is $49$ divisible by $14$ either. No surprise, given that $14$ is composite, not prime.

Now consider $p = -7$, $a = 2$, $b = 49$. Then $ab = 98$ is divisible by $p$, just like before. Although $2$ is not divisible by $-7$, $49$ is. We can choose other $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = 98$, but it is guaranteed that in each case we will find that $-7$ is a divisor of either $a$ or $b$, if not both. Indeed $-7$ is a prime number.

Working in $\mathbb{Z}$ this might not seem like such a big deal. Look at almost any other number ring and this becomes a very important distinction.

Answer (score 3):

When $R$ is a UFD (unique factorization domain, e.g. $R = \mathbf Z$) then the following two concepts are equivalent for an element $p \in R$ and $p$ is not zero and $p$ is not a unit:

- $p$ is irreducible, meaning whenever $p$ is written as a product of two other elements of $R$, i.e. $p = ab$, then either $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. Necessarily, if $p$ divides $a$ or $b$ the other has to be a unit in $R$. For example, if $p \mid a$ and we write $a = pc$ for some $c \in R$ then $p = ab = pcb$ so $1 = cb$ and hence $b$ has an inverse, namely $c$.
- $p$ is prime, meaning whenever $p$ divides a product of two other elements, i.e. $p \mid ab$, then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

The classical definition of a prime number is an *irreducible* element of $\mathbf Z$ and prime numbers are indeed prime elements as defined above.

Historically, when attempting to prove Fermat's Last Theorem ($x^n + y^n = z^n$ has no solutions for $n \ge 3$ except when one of $x, y$ or $z$ is zero) mathematicians (such as Dedekind and Kummer) noticed that when $p$ is prime, we can factor $x^p + y^p$ as

$$ (x + y)(x + \zeta y)\cdots(x + \zeta^{p-1} y) \tag{1}$$

where $\zeta$ is a principal $p$-th root of unity. (It was already known that if Fermat's Last Theorem could be proved for prime exponents, it holds for all exponents.)

What was noticed is that if $x^p + y^p = z^p$ then $(1)$ and $z^p$ are two different factorizations of $z^p$. The issue is, $\mathbf Z[\zeta]$ isn't always a UFD.

This prompted a more serious look at rings which aren't UFDs but still come from adjoining roots of polynomials, such as $\zeta$ to the integers.

For example, in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ we have non-unique factorization:

$$ 21 = 3 \cdot 7 = (1 + 2\sqrt{-5}) \cdot (1 - 2\sqrt{-5}).$$

The idea to solve this is that somehow there were a larger class of "ideal numbers" in which we get a unique factorization. That is, there would be "ideal primes" $\mathfrak{p}_1, \mathfrak{p}_2, \mathfrak{p}_3, \mathfrak{p}_4$ such that

$$ 3 = \mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2, 7 = \mathfrak{p}_3\mathfrak{p}_4 $$

and

$$ (1 + 2\sqrt{-5}) = \mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_3, (1 - 2\sqrt{-5}) = \mathfrak{p}_2\mathfrak{p}_4 $$

these "ideal primes" give us a unique factorization of $21$ into "ideal numbers".

Well, when you look at what properties you want of an "ideal number" you find that they should basically be defined in terms of divisibility. Here, $\mathfrak{p_1}$ and $\mathfrak{p_2}$ "divide" $3$.

Carrying on with this idea, you realize that an "ideal element" $\mathfrak{a}$ isn't anything more than the set of things it divides:

$$ \mathfrak{a} ``=" \{a \in R : \mathfrak a \mid a\}. $$

This is where the definition of an ideal inside a ring came from.

Of course, in a ring that isn't a $UFD$, talking about "factoring numbers" isn't well-defined. So what mathematicians did is move away from the notion of irreducible elements to the notion of prime elements which can be phrased naturally in terms of ideals. Specifically, an ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime if whenever $ab \in \mathfrak p$ (in terms of "ideal primes" this says that $\mathfrak p \mid ab$) then either $a \in \mathfrak p$ or $b \in \mathfrak p$.

In a UFD, all these notions are the same:

$p$ is irreducible if and only if $p$ is prime if and only if the ideal $(p)$ is a prime ideal.

---

This explanation of "ideal elements" is based off of Chapter 1.3 in Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*.